# How to get the lat and lon from database to google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am using this code to get the google map.it has the lat and lon value, but i have a database which has lat and lon. i want to use the lat and lon from database in this map,how to do this?

this is my google map javascript

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(12.91869,77.594051);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
    });
    var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: latlng,
        });
    map.openInfoWindow(latlng,
                       document.createTextNode("Hello, world"));
  }
</script>
```

Can anyone help me...?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: What part are you having problems with?

Comment: now i have directly given the lat and lon to variable latlng.but i want those values to be fetched from database.

Comment: Your code makes no attempt at fetching anything from a database. You should give it a try first and then post a question if and when you're having problems, but don't expect others to just write your code for you.

Comment: You're going to have to use a server-side language to read from the database. There's a huge choice, depending on your own experience and what's available to you on your server, PHP, .net, Java, Ruby, ColdFusion, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a method you can follow to go ahead-

Firstly load the latlng values from the database and store them in an array.

Then pass this array of latlng's to a javascript function that will display this latlng values on the map. The function will essentially contain a loop that will display each of these latlng's one by one on the map along with a marker.

You should first try working with an array of latlng's hardcoded in an array of javascript. Then it would be easy dealing with values retrieved from a database.